# Linear Mixed Effects Model not finishing in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a problem with a linear mixed effects model not completing in R.

I use the package [lmekin](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/coxme/versions/2.2-5/topics/lmekin) to run the model, as I am fitting a kinship matrix as a random effect.  The formula I am using is:

> model <- lmekin(disease ~ score + age + (1|IID), data=phenotype_df,
>   varlist=kinship_mx)

`phenotype_df` is a dataframe, with 12000 individuals, each with a disease status (1 or 0), a score and their age.  (Note: I am treating the disease status here as quantitative).
`kinship_mx` is a kinship matrix, ie. a positive-definite matrix (12000x12000) with diagonals ~0.5.

This model runs in around 1 minute when I use ~1000 individuals.  However, I left the model to run with all 12000 individuals on our large server and it has not finished after 5 days.  Could anyone suggest a reason as to why this is happening and if there are any solutions to enable the model to complete?

Comment: In my experience that makes no sense at all. 12000 is not ridiculous in size and what you are asking it to do, is relatively simple . If you can check the system profiler/task manager to see if it is actually still running. Then I would try running the script on your local machine adding 1000  each a time and see if you can get an error message at some point which you could debug.

Comment: Just to reply for more information - I checked `top` and it is definately still running.  I have been trying the "adding 1000" - it took 50 minutes to run with 2000 individuals.  Still running with the other increments.

Comment: If that is the case, you might want to try using one of the multi-core libraries from r to spread the work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer this question - they finished after three weeks.  It just takes a long time.